# Get an URL from SCNScene

Tags: swift, arkit, scnscene

In the [apple example code for ARKit](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/environmental_analysis/placing_objects_and_handling_3d_interaction), they provided a `VirtualObject`class that load Scn files from `Models.scnassets`.

```
 static let availableObjects: [VirtualObject] = {
    let modelsURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "Models.scnassets", withExtension: nil)!

    let fileEnumerator = FileManager().enumerator(at: modelsURL, includingPropertiesForKeys: [])!

    return fileEnumerator.compactMap { element in
        let url = element as! URL

        guard url.pathExtension == "scn" && !url.path.contains("lighting") else { return nil }

        return VirtualObject(url: url)
    }
}()
```

Let's say I have a SCNScene that download from a sever, the first question is, this SCNScene is similar to scn files?
if yes, how can I add this SCNScene to the above function, and get its URL to add it in the return `VirtualObject(url: url)` ? I stuck in this part for days, would be appreciated if anyone can help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store it in the file manager and get url from there

if scene is your `SCNScene`:

```
static let availableObjects: [VirtualObject] = {
    
    var virtualObjects: [VirtualObject] = []

    let paths = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)[0]
    let url = paths.appendingPathComponent("chair.scn")
    
    scene.write(to: url, options: nil, delegate: nil) { float, error, pointer in
        if let error = error {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
            return
        }
    }
    
    if let objects = VirtualObject(url: url) {
        virtualObjects.append(objects)
    }
    return virtualObjects
}
```